# Database connection onto an module

Tags: database

I created a module and I want to add a database connection for my module. In looking for an answer, I noticed the `getConnection()` method of the `Database` class.

I tried this code in a controller.

```php
$connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('moduleunicef','password');
```

I added the following code in the setting.php file.

```php
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'moduleunicef',
  'username' => 'theuser',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'prefix' => '',
);
```

I get the following error message.

> Drupal\Core\Database\ConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified database connection is not defined: root in Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() (line 366 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('moduleunicef', 'password')
> Drupal\unicef42\Controller\PbRouteController->index()
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
> Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
> call_user_func_array(Object, Array)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
> Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)

I tried the following code and it works.

```php
$connection = \Drupal::database();
```

What parameters do I need to pass to `Database::getConnection()`?

Comment: Be aware that direct database access is discouraged in Drupal 8. Instead, one should use the Entity system.

Comment: In Drupal 8 you can use [`Database::setActiveConnection()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Database.php/function/Database%3A%3AsetActiveConnection/8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    $database_info = array(
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'database' => $dbname,
        'username' => $dbuser,
        'password' => $dbpass,
        'driver' => 'mysql'
    );

// Add connection info
    Database::addConnectionInfo('externaldb', 'default', $database_info);

// Test connection
    try {
        $connection = Database::getConnection('default', 'externaldb');
        $caught     = false;
        return array($caught, $connection);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Ups connection failed
        $connection = NULL;
        form_set_error('syncsae_config_host', t('Connection failed.'));

        $errornumber  = $e->getCode();
        $errormessage = $e->getMessage();

        drupal_set_message(t('Error: @errornum.', array(
            '@errornum' => $errornumber
        )), 'error');
        drupal_set_message(t('Error description: @errormes.', array(
            '@errormes' => $errormessage
        )), 'error');

        $caught = true;
        return array($caught, $connection);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code to change connection and query a database table.

In the settings.php file, add the following code.

```php
databases['customer_db']['default'] = [
  'driver' => 'pgsql',
  'database' => 'drupal',
  'username' => 'drupal',
  'password' => 'drupal',
  'host' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
  'port' => '5432',
  'prefix' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\pgsql',
];
```

To query the database, use the following code.

```php
$db = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default', 'customer_db'); 
print_r($db->databaseType());
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customer");
```